# Hats or No Hats?

Tags: discussion, promotional-events

### Da Happenin'

Last year, on our Gaming site, we hosted an event called [Hat Dash](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/), where users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges).

[image: Hats!]

Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear". For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor.

This year we have the opportunity to participate in this event if we so do desire.

### Da Deats

- The event will run from 19 December 2012 to 4 January 2013.
- Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on http://winterba.sh.
  That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other
  details of the event.
- Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats,
  and/or are generally anti-hat will have an "I hate hats" option available..
- The only visual change to the site itself will be the presence of the hats
  and the "I hate hats" button in the footer.

### Da Vote

Since we are a <s>aristocracy masked as a democracy</s> democracy, we will do take a vote to decide whether we would like to participate. Simply vote for the choice you agree with and that's it. You're done.

**We only have until 28 November 2012 to inform Stack Exchange of our decision though. So make sure to vote!**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Yes! We want hats!

Comment: I've told them we are in. We gonna get hats!