# Hats or No Hats? (2013)

Tags: discussion, promotional-events

It's that [time of year again](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/349/20): Winter Bash 2013.

Details:

> This event will run from 16 December 2013 to 3 January 2014. Users
> will be able to see their entire hat collection at http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com.
> That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and
> other details of the event.
>
> Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see
> hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option
> available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats
> will go back into storage.
>
> The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be
> the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

We have to get the word to the community team by December 1st, so let us know what you think!

### Update: I've let the community team know we're interested.  Thanks for the votes!

Comment: Can we keep the hats? (permanent stat on profile page or special badges like bronze for 10 hats in one season, silver for 100, gold for 75% all published hats plus at least one hidden)

Comment: I don't think that's possible--I'm pretty sure it's just for fun.

Comment: @hildred You could probably print them out and glue them into photographs ;)

Answer (score 10):

## Yes please, give us hats!

I support Winter Bash 2013.

Answer (score -1):

## No thanks, keep your hats to yourself.