# Hats or No Hats (2015) {NOT Pi Hardware add-ons!}

Tags: discussion, promotional-events, user-interface

I've never participated in such a thing before but I see this site has done so before, in at least [2012](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349/hats-or-no-hats) and [2013](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/419/hats-or-no-hats-2013); but is it something that is available **this year**?

*<strike>I was going to post two opposite answers and hope for votes - but then I realised that this sort of action for the previous year's question/answerers could be seen as a cheap shot at boosting reputation... so I will just leave it unanswered and invite comments instead. {Of course if anyone wishes to reward this modesty I won't object.}</strike> With no reputation to work for on the Meta Exchange: sod it, go on and vote...! 8->*

Comment: The moderator emails were sent out today (they ask us if we want to participate), so we'll discuss it and reply shortly. My guess is *yes* we will be participating :)

Comment: p.s. meta votes don't really mean anything, and they don't count toward your site rep ;)

Comment: OK, then, lets us use this post to canvas.

Comment: Do we have any say in this? Why vote ^^

Comment: Um, I wasn't meaning to tread on anyone's toes, 8-O .

I *thought* if any others wanted to comment / express their opinions this would do (I thought the discussion tag would be relevant for this); also I was following the example of [jandjorgensen's](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/20/jandjorgensen) post for 2013...

Comment: ... no offense (and none taken). I am just curious and have no idea whether the hat situation thingy is up to the vote or not ;)

Comment: For those that don't know... http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/ http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Jivings After a week, is there any sign of a "reply shortly"?

Comment: @SlySven Based on the votes below, we will be participating :)

Comment: Great, when I hear (or *see* the first Hat on RPSE) I'll accept the relevant answer!

Comment: IT HAS BEGUN ;)

Comment: Hat away....! [|8-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you vote for this answer to say "I would like to have the chance to earn/gain a short-term, pointless, but perhaps fun, extra graphic on my Avatar for the next month or so until some time in January 2016."

Comment: As an individual user you can choose to participate or not. If you participate "your heart might grow three sizes in just one day"

Comment: Well [Cardiomegaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiomegaly) doesn't sound like fun - though that is not the same as being *big-hearted* I suppose. 8-P

Comment: in case you weren't familiar with the reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGSs33DQ1F0

Answer (score 0):

"What a load of *old-hat* - just because some, possibly juvenile users of some *other* Stack Exchange communities want to play around with ephemeral, meaningless, eye-candy, this is not relevant to me and my interests, even if it *is* Christmas.

[Bah Humbug!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebenezer_Scrooge)"